# How can I pull in a table from a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to pull a table of statistics from a broadway show page. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
springsteen_url = 'https://www.ibdb.com/broadway-production/springsteen-on-broadway-515480#Statistics'
springsteen_response = requests.get(springsteen_url)
springsteen_soup = BeautifulSoup(springsteen_response.text, 'html.parser')
```

I found the table tag and there were 2 named "striped" I selected the first one:

```
statistics = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "striped"})
table1 = statistics[0]
```

I am able to create a df and populate the headers but the rows/cells won't populate:

```
# Defining of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Week Ending', 'Gross', '% Gross Pot.', 'Attendance', '% Capacity'])

# Collecting Ddata
for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):    
    # Find all data for each column
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    
    if(columns != []):
        week = columns[0].text.strip()
        gross = columns[1].text.strip()
        grosspot = columns[2].span.contents[0].strip('&0.')
        attendance = columns[3].span.contents[0].strip('&0.')
        capacity = columns[4].span.contents[0].strip('&0.')

        df = df.append({'Week Ending': week,  'Gross': gross, '% Gross Pot.': grosspot, 'Attendance': attendance, '% Capacity': capacity}, ignore_index=True)
```

```
df.head()
```

Comment: When I inspect the contents, I see that the data is defined inside a javascript variable (`springsteen_soup.find_all("script")[4]`). Perhaps it is easier to extract it using a regex.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still struggling with how to then pull in specifically the "function initStatistics(id)" section and format it into my code above to match the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I found a mistake in your code that you used `springsteen_response.text` in `BeautifulSoup(springsteen_response.text, 'html.parser')` instead of `springsteen_response.content` so try to avoid it to not have problems with character encoding. The `.content` attribute holds raw bytes, which can be decoded better.

I also coded a solution to your problem with [`Ali Değer Ozbakir`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10811698/ali-de%C4%9Fer-ozbakir)'s hint to extract data with regex. I explained things in code comments, but in short you need to use [Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) to be able to extract a data within `<script>` tag then extract a group from that regex and finally you have to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse a data string because the string didn't match [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format so you couldn't parse it.

**Code:**

```py
import re
import ast
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

springsteen_url = 'https://www.ibdb.com/broadway-production/springsteen-on-broadway-515480#Statistics'
springsteen_response = requests.get(springsteen_url)
springsteen_soup = BeautifulSoup(springsteen_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find a <script> tag which have "grossdata" text inside
scriptdata = springsteen_soup.find("script", text=re.compile("grossdata")).string

# this is a regular expression
# ? after space means that space may or may not occur in string
# . (dot) means we are matching any character
# + sign when used with previous dot means that any character need to occur at least one time
# at the end ";" may or may not occur
grossdata_pattern = re.compile(r"grossdata ?= ?({.+});?")
grossdata_search = grossdata_pattern.search(scriptdata)

if grossdata_search:
    # We are extracting here a second group (first is the whole string from "grossdata" to ";")
    # the second group is simply between parentheses "()"
    grossdata = grossdata_search.group(1)
else:
    print("Failed to locate string to match regex.")

# Because of a data didn't match JSON format we couldn't parse to it
# so we need to use safe evaluation of a python code
# to make it a python dictionary
grossdata = ast.literal_eval(grossdata)

grossdata_2018 = grossdata[0]

df = pd.DataFrame(grossdata_2018)

# Remove unwanted columns
df.drop([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Week Ending', 'Gross', '% Gross Pot.', 'Attendance', '% Capacity']

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Week Ending       Gross % Gross Pot. Attendance % Capacity
0    Jun 3, 2018  $1,929,448         101%      3,792       100%
1   Jun 10, 2018  $2,402,103         101%      4,740       100%
2   Jun 17, 2018  $1,930,270         101%      3,792       100%
3   Jun 24, 2018  $2,411,075         101%      4,740       100%
4    Jul 1, 2018  $1,929,003         101%      3,792       100%
5   Jul 15, 2018  $2,410,195         101%      4,740       100%
6   Jul 22, 2018    $964,163         101%      1,895       100%
7   Jul 29, 2018  $1,931,618         101%      3,792       100%
8   Aug 12, 2018  $1,931,445         101%      3,792       100%
9   Aug 19, 2018  $2,406,003         101%      4,729       100%
10  Aug 26, 2018  $1,928,960         101%      3,792       100%
11   Sep 2, 2018  $1,930,020         101%      3,792       100%
12   Sep 9, 2018  $1,932,670         101%      3,792       100%
13  Sep 30, 2018  $1,927,620         101%      3,792       100%
14   Oct 7, 2018  $2,410,528         101%      4,740       100%
15  Oct 14, 2018  $1,929,795         101%      3,792       100%
16  Oct 21, 2018  $2,414,700         101%      4,740       100%
17  Oct 28, 2018  $1,937,995         102%      3,792       100%
18   Nov 4, 2018  $2,424,880         102%      4,740       100%
19  Nov 11, 2018  $1,935,170         101%      3,792       100%
20  Nov 18, 2018  $2,423,700         102%      4,740       100%
21   Dec 2, 2018  $1,929,320         101%      3,792       100%
22   Dec 9, 2018  $2,415,700         101%      4,740       100%
23  Dec 16, 2018  $1,895,695         100%      3,792       100%
```